# Directshow, webcam, strange values of timestamp?

Tags: timestamp, directshow

I am working on a project where I need to sample images from an USB cam and for each image do some calculations. And by "accident" I printed the timestamp that comes with each cam frame. 
I am grabbing 1600x1200 frames at a speed of up to 20 frames / second. (usually ~15frames/sec)

20 frames / second = 50ms between each image.

But why can I find timestamps with only ~8ms in between?

For example:
4.901... and 4.909...

Is the timestamp not that accurate or should I look for an error in my code?

The timestamp is printed directly in the "sampleCB" method in directshow.

[image: timestamp for images from webcam.]

Answer (score 0):

An upstream filter timestamps the samples - you get what you get. In particular, you might want to check the graph topology to see what exactly upstream filters you have there and where the video comes from. There might be additional filters between the camera and the Sample Grabber.